# Wireless Hosted Network client isolation

Tags: networking, windows-7, wifi, netsh, wlan

I would like to know if there is an option to enable/disable client isolation when using the Wireless Hosted Network feature, present in most windows 7 laptops with a capable wireless adapter, and what is its official default behavior. I can't verify it because I only have one server and one client to play with.

I set it up the usual way on the server machine:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=aaa key=12345678
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

As a side note, for client ip assignment I have a DHCP server in the server ready (i can modify its source code if needed), but the self-defined APIPA addresses would also do just fine because the chance of collisions should be negligeable for my needs.

I need to ensure that clients wirelessly connected to that network cannot discover each other and send data to each other through the server. The server should be the only thing they ever see.